# After removing smart scopes Unity with Active Blur becomes very slow

Tags: unity, 13.04, compiz, unity-dash, lenses

Before testing smart scopes my computer ran Unity perfectly. The dash opened instantly when either pressing the super key or clicking the icon. I tried out smart scopes and attempted to use it but unity became incredibly slow to open, nothing like it shows in the demo videos. It would take about 5 seconds to open unity and even longer to search. I removed smart scopes and the problem persisted. Enabling Static Blur or No Blur in Compiz Config Settings Manager speeds unity back up but I want Unity to be functioning the way it was before with Active Blur.

My computer specs are more than enough to run Unity.

- Intel Core i7-3520M CPU @ 2.90GHz × 4
- Intel Ivybridge Mobile Graphics
- 8 GBs of RAM

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the **dash blur** setting under the **unity-tweak-tool**?

Try with *static* and *no blur*, and see how it goes: if it works, you should notice it right away.

Comment: As I stated in the question, changing it to static and/or no blur speeds unity back up. I want unity to function the way it used to. It used to function just fine with active blur enabled I want it to do that again

Comment: I also want to know why it's functioning so slowly. With my hardware, that shouldn't happen

Comment: Sorry, think I posted it in the wrong place, as that fixed my problem ^_^.  (Got confused with so many opened tabs I had)